# Protect GPIO pin on ESP32 development board from accidental 12 V input

Tags: gpio, short-circuit, 12v, esp32, circuit-protection

I'm working on a project which involves connecting in series a lot of small cut strips (5-7 LEDs) of WS2815 powered by a separate 12 V PSU. They are controlled by GPIO of an ESP32 Dev Module powered by a separate 5 V PSU. The grounds of the two PSUs and the 5 V and 12 V are connected.

The soldering of strips is done in a very narrow space and since the 12 V pin and DI pin on a WS2815 are very close together, sometimes during working with the strip the 12 V gets shorted with DI and this burns the ESP32.

How can I protect the GPIO pin (which is working strictly as a LED signal) from accidental 12 V input which results in burned board?

I've spent half a day googling for GPIO protection but have not found specifically this case. The opinions differ from simple series resistors to Zeners to level shifters and more which makes everything extremely confusing for me. All I need is a protection during the testing stage; after the soldering and assembly is done, the protection can be removed.

I do not have an electrical engineering education and am learning as I go. I would really appreciate help on this. Burning boards without clue how to make it work is very frustrating.

Comment: Will it be a solution to not protect the GPIO pin, but to not work on the setup live, and have a defined procedure to avoid and make sure it won't blow up? Like doing the LED strip soldering first, then checking soldering problems before connecting it to power and MCU, and finally checking for wiring problems like shorts between 12V and data before applying power to project?

Comment: My procedure is the following:
1. Do the soldering.
2. Check for solder connections.
3. Assemble the LED strip in place (sometimes it means squeezing into a narrow groove)
4. Connect 12v PSU
5. Connect 5v PSU.
6. While ground is connected to the LED strip, connect 12v and then signal.

So I'm not doing it live. However during assembly sometimes it is impossible to see if the solder on terminals has moved. To risk several more boards is just not an option